# Object/Function hybrid

Tags: javascript, function, object

I've fiddled with many snippets, but this is the closest I have so far:

```
function Q(a){
  if(typeof a=="string"){
    var b=a[0],c=a.substring(1);
    return b=="#"?document.getElementById(c):b=="."?document.getElementsByClassName(c):document.getElementsByTagName(a);
  }
}

Q.setClass=function(b){a.className=b}
```

I want to be able to do `Q("#ID").setClass("testClass");`

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to return a wrapper object from `Q`, which implements `setClass`.

Comment: I tried doing this: http://hastebin.com/vavagazeci.coffee but it didn't work. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Since I don't know what you expect, I can't tell what exactly "didn't work". However, `{this:resp}` has no significance, other than setting the object's property `this` to `resp`. It doesn't impact the other function's `this` value. Maybe you just want `console.log(resp)` inside that function.

Comment: Just a last question: Is it possible to detect if a Q.prototype is issued? I want to return just the response if no command is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no object-function hybrid in your question. You want an `Q` (constructor/factory) *function* that yields an *object* which has a `setClass` (method) *function*.

This can for example be done like this:

```
function Q(el) {
  if (typeof el=="string") {
    var b = el.charAt(0),
        c = el.substring(1);
    el = b=="#"
         ? [document.getElementById(c)]
         : b=="."
           ? document.getElementsByClassName(c)
           : document.getElementsByTagName(a);
  }
  return {
    setClass: function(cls) {
      for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
        el[i].className = cls;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I sorted it out with @Felix Kling in the comments, but I'm accepting yours as he did not post as an answer (and your answer states it a bit more clearly). Thanks!